# «Критиковать невзирая на лица». Частица НЕ — слитно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Тут обнаружила в некоторых словарях В. Лопатина слитное написание, да и Грамота.ру упорно отвечает, что НЕ пишется вместе. А я-то верила Розенталю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ Грамоты: **невзирая на лица** (предлог).

[http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=не%20взирая%20на%20лица](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)

Это вполне допустимая правка: просто отменили раздельное написание в одном устойчивом выражении, чтобы исключений было поменьше.